# Change input background color and text using Script Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, css

I want to change input background color and text

**HTML**

```
   <input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_31468fa3_6955_464f_99a3_1a53cb733c3b$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="Guardar" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl40$g_31468fa3_6955_464f_99a3_1a53cb733c3b$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_31468fa3_6955_464f_99a3_1a53cb733c3b_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accesskey="O" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" target="_self">
```

with jQuery I think is something like:

```
.parent().css("background-color", "#5858FA")
```

but I don´t have an idea of how to select field. Regards

Comment: This is not related to SharePoint itself, but rather javascript/jQuery. Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306129/javascript-get-element-by-name
Please consider searching next time since you can find many answer for this by searching "How to select element by name with javascript".

Comment: I think you are better off selecting a parent container then grabbing the button, but it would be something like `$("button[name*='diidIOSaveItem']")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this -- https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

You can use selector this way for input button tag as well.

First change the background color as below:

```
$("input[value='Guardar']").css("background-color", "#5858FA");
```

then change the value as below:

```
$("input[value='Guardar']").val("NewBtnValue");
```

Comment: one more question, to hide button I just use `$("input[value='Guardar']").hide`?

Comment: @Ledwing You will have to use the present value for selecting the button. In this case if you have already changed the value of your button to `NewBtnValue`, the you will have to use `NewBtnValue` in your selector. e.g. `$("input[value='NewBtnValue']").hide();`